# How to create and open for editing a nonexistent file whose path is under the cursor in Vim?

Tags: vim

I’m trying Vim for the first couple of hours with Ruby on Rails, and I’m loving it so far.

Specifically, the `gf` command is great, but I miss something:
If the file under the cursor does not exist yet, `gf` returns an error.

Is there a command to actually create and open the file if it does not exist?
Or, what is the most straightforward way to create it?

Comment: Try looking here: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567

Comment: Yes, but the closest I see is 'gf', but its aim is going to the partial only if the file already exists, not create the file.

Comment: See duplicate on SU: http://superuser.com/questions/277325/create-a-file-under-the-cursor-in-vim

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One can define a custom variant of the `gf` command that opens
a new buffer if the file under the cursor does not exist:

```
:noremap <leader>gf :e <cfile><cr>
```

where the `:e` command could be replaced with `:tabe` (to open
the buffer for the new file in a separate tab) or another
file-opening command.

It is also possible to just create a file with the name under the
cursor without opening it; see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828317/create-a-file-under-the-cursor-in-vim/5829371#5829371) to a similar question
“[Create a file under the cursor in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828317/create-a-file-under-the-cursor-in-vim-migrated)”.

Comment: `:e <cfile>` is enough for occasional usage, since `<cfile>` grabs the same filename that would be chosen by `gf`

Comment: Doesnt work for me - I do have my files nested in subfolders. And sometimes I want to create a file in a subfolder from a file that is already in a subfolder. Is that a limitation? I typed that exact command (both the solution and the comment, I tried), and I also sourced my vimrc. It just says "Can't find file foo/bar.txt in path"

Comment: Is there anything to be said against skipping the `<leader>`? I.e.:
`:map gf :e <cfile><cr>`?

Comment: @BernhardWagner: Just that it will shadow the original `gf` mapping. Prefixing mappings with a non-conflicting leader key (see `:help mapleader`) is one of the recommended ways to avoid conflicts with existing mappings. However, if shadowing the built-in mapping is what you want, then, of course, your mapping should not use the leader.

Answer (score 2):

**gf** -> opens the file in a new tab

**cf** -> creates the file (if it doesn't exist) and opens it in new tab

```
nnoremap gf <C-W>gf 
noremap <leader>cf :call CreateFile(expand("<cfile>"))<CR>
function! CreateFile(tfilename)

    " complete filepath from the file where this is called
    let newfilepath=expand('%:p:h') .'/'. expand(a:tfilename)

    if filereadable(newfilepath)
       echo "File already exists"
       :norm gf
    else
        :execute "!touch ". expand(newfilepath)
        echom "File created: ". expand(newfilepath)
        :norm gf
    endif

endfunction
```

Comment: The accepted answer works only with files in the current dir, while this works in subdirs also

Comment: "cf" is bad because that would normally begin a "change mode", starting from the current cursor and until the next input character that is foudn on the current line.

Answer (score 2):

```
nnoremap <silent> gf :call JumpOrCreateFile()<CR>


function! JumpOrCreateFile()
 " Get the filename under the cursor
 let filename = expand("<cfile>")

 " Expand the tilde in the file path
 let expanded_filename = expand(filename)

 " Check if the file path starts with "./"
 if expanded_filename =~# '^\.\/'
   " Get the current directory of the editing file
   let current_directory = expand('%:p:h')

   " Create the full path by appending the relative file path
   let expanded_filename = current_directory . '/' . expanded_filename
 endif

 " Check if the file exists
 if !filereadable(expanded_filename)
   " Prompt the user for file creation with the full path
   let choice = confirm('File does not exist. Create "' . expanded_filename . '"?', "&Yes\n&No", 1)

   " Handle the user's choice
   if choice == 1
     " Create the file and open it
     execute 'edit ' . expanded_filename
   endif
 else
   " File exists, perform normal gf behavior
   execute 'normal! gf'
 endif
endfunction
```